# Assistance with a jquery content swelling effect

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a small "swell" effect with jquery .animate and .hover. the mousein event seems to work well, however, on the mouse out, the margin snaps back to the original position, the animates back to the original state. I need the element to expand, then go back without changing the position of any of the other elements.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(".nav-item").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).addClass('over');
            $(this).animate({
                width: '114px', 
                height:'114px', 
                margin: '-7px'}, 
                300);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass('over');
            $(this).animate({
                width:'100px',
                height:'100px',
                margin: '0'},
                300);}
    );
});
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="nav-item"></div>
    <div class="nav-item"></div>
    <div class="nav-item"></div>
    <div class="nav-item"></div>
    <div class="nav-item"></div>
    <div class="nav-item"></div>
    <div class="nav-item"></div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.nav-item {
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px #000000 solid;
border-collapse: collapse;
float: left;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
}

.over {
z-index: 1;
}
```

I have this up at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCxzs/).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't create an answer myself (jQ animation not my strong point!) but I can't help suspecting the floating layout will be a continual headache. You might have to have a static layout or convert the hover'd element's layout to absolute dynamically while animating and then back to float after it shrinks back down.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I could do....

the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var left=0;
    $(".nav-item").each(function(){
        $(this).css({left:left=left+100});
        console.log(left);
    })
    $(".nav-item").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('over');
        $(this).animate({
            width: '114px',
            height: '114px',
            margin: '-7px'
        }, 300);
        },function() {
            $(this).removeClass('over');
            $(this).animate({
                width: '100px',
                height: '100px',
                margin: '0'
            }, 300);
        }
    )
    })
```

and some changes in the css also

```
.nav-item {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px #000000 solid;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

.over {
    z-index: 1;   
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try the suggestions when I get back in front of my code.

Comment: Tried suggestions here, but it still didn't work to my satisfaction. I found a plugin called hoverpulse that, with slight modification, works perfectly for what I am trying to accomplish.

If anyone is interested in this plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/hoverpulse/

Answer (score 0):

Tried suggestions here, but it still didn't work to my satisfaction. I found a plugin called hoverpulse that, with slight modification, works perfectly for what I am trying to accomplish. If anyone is interested in this plugin: [hoverpulse plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/hoverpulse)